# How to add backstack to viewpager with fragmentManager and FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, back-stack

How to add backstack to  viewpager

How do we manage to go to previous fragment from the current fragment

I have got the fragment part working , now I am trying to learn to manage the naviation of fragments by the back button

Here is the main activity which contains three fragments

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    ViewPager viewpager = null;
    LinearLayout lay;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstancestate) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstancestate);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        viewpager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        viewpager.setPageTransformer(true, new DepthPageTransformer());
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        viewpager.setAdapter(new myAdaper(fragmentManager));
        PagerTitleStrip pagerTitleStrip = (PagerTitleStrip)findViewById(R.id.pager_title_strip);
          pagerTitleStrip.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 24);
         // pagerTitleStrip.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
        }
class myAdaper extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public myAdaper(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Fragment fragment = null;
        if (i == 0) {
            fragment = new fragmentA();

        }
        if (i == 1) {
            fragment = new fragmentB();


        }

        if (i == 2) {

            fragment = new fragmentC();


        }
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        String title = new String();
        SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder(""+ position);
        if (position == 0) {
            return "Tab1";

        }
        if (position == 1) {
            return "Tab2";

        }
        if (position == 2) {
            return "Tab3";

        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

And the fragments are

```
public class fragmentA extends Fragment{

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
            ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a,container, false);
    }

}
```

these are repeated with same code just diff color for the other two fragments fragment B and fragment C

now if

I am on fragment C i want ot go back to fragment B and

if I am on Fragment B i want to go to Fragment A

Answer (score 0):

Store in a variable wich is your current page (you can get it with the [ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html)). Then override the `onBackPressed()`method of your activity and change to the previous of your viewpager with `setCurrentItem(int item)`

If you are in the first fragment just call `super.onBackPressed()`